# how is storing private keys in the TPM helpful?

Tags: private-key, tpm

I am not understanding one thing about the TPM.

I have to backup the private keys somewhere else anyways in case I loose my machine. If I backup the keys somewhere else then what is the significance of using the TPM to store my private keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a hacker overtakes your machine, he is unable to  copy the private key.

Of course as long as he has access to your machine, he is still able to use it to decrypt stuff.